# glyphicon button in asp.net content placeholder

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

i am creating a button dynamically using `Asp.Net` `Content Placeholder` but unable to give it a finishing look

here is what i want to create:
[image]

**Asp.Net Code**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i> Add more" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-xs" OnClick="Button1_Click" Style="margin-left: 435px"></asp:LinkButton>
```

the `asp.net` code works fine

**C# CODE**

```
LinkButton add_more = new LinkButton();
add_more.Text = "Add more";
add_more.Click += new System.EventHandler(Button1_Click);
add_more.Width = 75;
add_more.Height = 25;
add_more.Attributes.Add("style", "margin-left:435px");
add_more.Attributes.Add("Class", "glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn btn-default btn-xs");
```

and it looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuo should add `<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i> Add more` between the openning and ending tags of the linkbutton

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-xs" OnClick="Button1_Click" Style="margin-left: 435px">
<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i> Add more

</asp:LinkButton>
```

Ok, If you want to add a LinkButton to PlaceHolder, do the following.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeHolder" runat="server" >
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

In code behind,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton add_more = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton();
            add_more.Text = "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i> Add more";
            add_more.Click += new System.EventHandler(Button1_Click);
            add_more.Attributes.Add("style", "margin-left:435px");
            add_more.Attributes.Add("Class", "btn btn-default btn-xs");


            placeHolder.Controls.Add(add_more);

        }
```

Comment: i want to create it in placeholder

Comment: there is one more problem
when i click on add more button and new button appears it looks just like previous button like i mentioned in question (that weird button) and when i click on that button i changes to original button that i want
i have clean and rebuild the solution changed the browse but results are same